# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzbqv.class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

The app keeps on crashing continuously, can anyone help? First there was dex error I added the dependency and also enabled multiDex but still no luck..

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.example.parth.newapp1, PID: 21233
                                                   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbpa;)V in class Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbra; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra' appears in /data/app/com.example.parth.newapp1-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes6.dex)
                                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpj.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpl.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpl.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.zzWG(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getReference(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.example.parth.newapp1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6323)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

The line 29 on MainActivity: 
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference.child("Blog");

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.parth.newapp1"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

            multiDexEnabled true
        }

        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
        compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0 will have a transitive dependency to either 
 com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'  or  'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1 which will cause the duplicate entry issue. So keep the actual dependency you need and remove others.

Comment: thank you for the answer but the real prob was I used com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0 instead of com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.1.1 which is compatible with  'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1 ...
Anyways thank you!